# Integer solution to $B(J-T)+1 = J(T-B), 31 \leqslant B < T < J \leqslant 49$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I found the following equation in some old notes:
$$
B(J-T)+1=J(T-B) \tag 1
$$
I don't remember where I got the problem but it is something like this: There are three brothers, James, Ted and Bob. James the eldest is in his forties, and Bob the youngest is at least 31 years old. The product of James's age and the (positive) difference between the other two brothers' is one more than the product of Bob's age and the (positive) difference between James's and Ted's. What are their ages?

The solution I came up with was to apply Simon's favorite factoring trick on (1) and I got
$$
T^2 - 2 = (2B-T)(2J-T) \tag 2
$$

Note that $J>T>B$, and $32 \le T \le 48, 14\le 2B-T\le 46, 41 \le 2J-T \le 66$. So I just manually (via Excel) checked all factors of the following 17 numbers: $32^2-2, 32^2-2, \ldots, 48^2-2$, and found only one solution $J=44, T=39, B=35$.

I would like to know:

1. If there's a better approach (James gives this as an interview question to someone looking for a job in his firm);
2. If anybody could find a source of the problem.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: One small thing I noticed is that if $T$ is even, then the left side has just one factor of $2$ while the right side has at least $2$ factors of $2$, so you would only need to check for odd $T$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, that's a great observation. And when $T$ is odd, there are only three cases when $T^2-2$ is not prime. Still, I remember in the original problem James gives this as an interview question to someone. So I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: You're welcome for my observation. This might not help much, but here's another one. Continuing with the concept of parity, with your $(1)$, since $T$ is, then if $J$ is odd, the LHS is odd, so the RHS shows $B$ must be even. If $J$ is even instead, the RHS is even, so the LHS shows $B$ must be odd. In other words, $J$ and $B$ must have different parities.

Comment: Just one more observation which combines my $2$ above. From our original equation, you get $2BJ - BT - JT  + 1 = 0 \implies T(B + J) = 2BJ + 1 \implies T = \frac{2BJ + 1}{B + J}$. Since $2BJ + 1$ is odd, this means $B + J$ is odd, i.e., have different parities, and $T$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many solutions. If you have one $J>T>B>0$ you get a new one  (bigger)

There is more variety: we can begin with column vector
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and multiply on the left by a square matrix

as in
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
45 & -1 & 28 \\
40 & -1 & 24 \\
36 & -1 & 21
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
44 \\
39 \\
35
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
  6     -1      1 transposed        6      4      3
  4     -1      0 transposed       -1     -1     -1
  3     -1      0 transposed        1      0      0

 15     -1      6 transposed       15     12     10
 12     -1      4 transposed       -1     -1     -1
 10     -1      3 transposed        6      4      3

 20     -6      1 transposed       20     15     12
 15     -4      1 transposed       -6     -4     -3
 12     -3      1 transposed        1      1      1

 28     -1     15 transposed       28     24     21
 24     -1     12 transposed       -1     -1     -1
 21     -1     10 transposed       15     12     10

 35     -6      6 transposed       35     21     15
 21     -4      3 transposed       -6     -4     -3
 15     -3      2 transposed        6      3      2

 42    -15      1 transposed       42     35     30
 35    -12      1 transposed      -15    -12    -10
 30    -10      1 transposed        1      1      1

 45     -1     28 transposed       45     40     36
 40     -1     24 transposed       -1     -1     -1
 36     -1     21 transposed       28     24     21
```

Comment: No I have $49 \ge J>T>B \ge 31$.

Comment: I just edited the title to make it more clear.